# Erlang : Use of `Ref` in query and response

Tags: erlang

I am reading [LearnYouSomeErlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/finite-state-machines) and found the code below :

My question is that why do we need `Ref` in `event` function.
I think the reason given is that `Ref` is like request-id.

if i send multiple requests to `dont_give_crap` and when i get back replies, `Ref` in response tells me which id it is.

However, since `event` is blocking and i am sending only one request, in which situation, will i be able to send multiple requests from same process to `dont_give_crap process` ? What is the purpose of `Ref` ?

```
-module(cat_fsm).
-export([start/0, event/2]).

start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> dont_give_crap() end).

event(Pid, Event) ->
    Ref = make_ref(), % won't care for monitors here
    Pid ! {self(), Ref, Event},
    receive
    {Ref, Msg} -> {ok, Msg}
    after 5000 ->
        {error, timeout}
    end.

dont_give_crap() ->
    receive
    {Pid, Ref, _Msg} -> Pid ! {Ref, meh};
    _ -> ok
    end,
    io:format("Switching to 'dont_give_crap' state~n"),
    dont_give_crap().
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is that why do we need Ref

It's like a verification code.  Any other process can send your process a message if it has your process's Pid.

> I think the reason given is that Ref is like request-id.

Ref is more like a reply-id.  It's an id that a process expects to receive in a reply.  If you write:

```
receive
    Msg ->  %%do something
end
```

then any message sent to your process's mailbox will match that pattern, and you won't know where it came from.  And if you write:

```
receive
    {Pid, Msg} ->  %%do something
end
```

you still can't be sure that the message came from process Pid.  Another one of your processes might have multiple Pids it is replying to and accidentally used the wrong Pid for the message.

But if you send a Ref with your request to process Pid, then process Pid can reply with a message that contains the Ref it received and its Pid, then you can extract the message containing that Ref and the sender's Pid from your mailbox and be sure it came from process Pid (well, actually process Pid could send the Ref to some other process, so you still can't be absolutely certain).

If you had an erlang application with 1,000's of processes sending 100's of messages to each other, it might be more error prone if you only verified where replies came from by Pid.

Edit: I was just reading about gen_udp and sockets, and it turns out that some servers can duplicate a reply.  Suppose that happens, and a client extracts the first reply from the mailbox like this:

```
receive
    {Pid, Msg1} -> Msg1
end
```

Then the client sends a second request and waits for the reply:

```
receive
    {Pid, Msg2} -> Msg2
end
```

Well, that pattern will extract the duplicate reply to the first request--not the reply to the second request.  But if a unique Ref and been sent with both the first and second requests:

```
Pid = ...,
Ref1 = ...,
Pid ! {self(), Ref1, Msg1},
receive
    {Pid, Ref1, Reply1} -> Reply1
end,

Ref2 = ...,
Pid ! {self(), Ref2, Msg2},
receive
    {Pid, Ref2, Reply2} -> Reply2
end.
```

then the second receive would not match a duplicate reply to the first request.  That is a concrete example of a good use of a Ref.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Use of `Ref` in query and response**

Each process has their own mailbox like post box at home. Mailbox is the entry point for sending any request to any process.

As per your code you want a response back from a particular process. So
you have to specify expected process pid in the place of message extraction from mailbox.

2. **Will i be able to send multiple requests from same process to dont_give_crap process ? What is the purpose of Ref ?**

which is not possible. To send multiple request from process A to process B.  A -> B, i.e) If A sends a blocking message to B then A is in a block,  means it will not accept any other message from any other process.

Each message will differ by the pattern match of message structure